# Вызов функции js

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, ajax

Есть два файла со скриптами. В одном есть функция. А как в другом скрипте вызвать функцию, которая находится в первом скрипте? Спасибо за ответы)

Первый скрипт:

```
 function compareInit() {
    new InSales.Compare({
        _textAdd: 'Добавлено',
        _textLink: 'К сравнению',
        selector: 'a.add_to_compare',
        draw: function(products) {
            if (products.length == 0) {
                $('.compare-notice').slideDown();
                $('#compare_div').slideUp('fast');
            }
            var compareCount = $('#compare_table .item').length;
            var compareCountNames = 'товар';
            if (compareCount > 1) {
                compareCountNames = 'товара';
            }
            var compareCountMsg = 'Вы сравниваете ' + compareCount + ' ' + compareCountNames
            $('.compare_count').html(compareCountMsg);
            if (!$("#compare_table .same").length) {
                $(".compare_show_similar, .compare_hide_similar").hide();
            } else {
                $(".compare_show_similar, .compare_hide_similar").show();
            }

            var text = '';
            console.log(products.length)
            if (products.length == 0) {
                text += '<div class="noforcompare">Нет товаров для сравнения</div>';
                $('#compare_div').html('<p>Товары для сравнения не выбраны</p><p><a href="/"  class="button" title="На главную">На главную</a></p>');
            } else {
                text += '<ol id="compare-items">'
                $(products).each(function(index, product) {
                    text += '<li class="item odd"><a href="javascript:;" rel="' + product.id + '" class="remove_compare btn-remove">удалить</a><p class="product-name"><a href="/product/?product_id=' + product.id + '">' + product.title + '</a></p></li>';
                });
                text += '</ol><div class="actions"><button type="button" class="button" onclick="location.href = \'/compares\'"><span><span>Сравнить</span></span></button></div>'
            }
            $('.block-compare .block-content').html(text);
        }
    });
}
compareInit();

$(document).on("click", "a.add_to_compare", function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
});

$(document).on("click", ".compare_show_similar", function() {
    $('.compare_links a').removeClass('active');
    $(".compare_show_similar").addClass('active');
    $("#compare_table .same").show();
});

$(document).on("click", ".compare_hide_similar", function() {
    $('.compare_links a').removeClass('active');
    $(".compare_hide_similar").addClass('active');
    $("#compare_table .same").hide();
});

$(document).on("click", '.compare_clear a', function() {
    show_preloader();
    $.cookie('compare', null);
    $('.compare-notice').slideDown();
    $('#compare_div').slideUp('fast');
    hide_preloader();
});
```

Второй скрипт:

```
  $(document).ready(function () {
    attachClickEvent();

});    
    var pInfScrLoading = false;
var pInfScrDelay = 250;
function pInfScrExecute() {
    pInfScrNode = $('.more').last();    
    pInfScrURL = $('.more a').last().attr("href");
    if(pInfScrNode.length > 0 && pInfScrNode.css('display') != 'none') {
        $.ajax({
            type: 'GET',
            url: pInfScrURL,
            beforeSend: function() {
              pInfScrLoading = true;
              pInfScrNode.clone().empty().insertAfter(pInfScrNode).append('<img src=\"https://assets3.insales.ru/assets/1/3389/732477/v_1482567929/build/loader.gif\" />');
              pInfScrNode.hide();         
            },
            success: function(data) {               
                pInfScrNode.next().remove();
                pInfScrNode.remove();
                var filteredData = $(data).find(".category-products");
                filteredData.insertBefore( $("#product-list-foot") );
                $('.pages_my').html($(data).find('.pages_my').html());
             compareInit();
                pInfScrLoading = false;             
                attachClickEvent();             
            },
            dataType: "html"
        });
    }
}
$("body").on("click", ".more a", function() {
      return run_filter($(this).attr("href"));
    });
function attachClickEvent(){
    $('p.more a').click(function(event){
        pInfScrExecute();
        event.stopPropagation();
        return false;
    });

}
```

Запускаются по порядку - 1 потом 2. Нужно во втором скрипте запустить функцию  `compareInit();`

Comment: все зависит от порядка подключения файлов и кода который находится внутри. Без этого невозможно ответить на вопрос

Comment: @Grundy - добавил

Comment: @Aleskandr, у вас в первом не закрыта функция ( `}` ). А во второй, почему вы её не вызываете в success?

Comment: @Yuri - извиняюсь, не все скопировал) При вызове в success такая же ошибка)

Comment: @Aleskandr, однако почему вы её не вызываете в success?

Comment: @Yuri При вызове в success такая же ошибка)

Comment: @Aleskandr, а если переместить эту функцию во второй скрипт -то что?

Comment: Да, перенес - все работает)

Comment: @Aleskandr, если в вопросе полные файлы - то все должно работать. Попробуй сделать [mcve] воспроизводящий проблему

Answer (score 0):

Скрипт №1:

```
function func() {
   ...
}
```

Скрипт №2:

```
func()
```

В head:

```
<script src="скрипт №1"></script>
<script src="скрипт №2"></script>
```

Comment: Спасибо Юрий, сделал как вы сказали - но ошибка: фукц.is not defined. Порядок не нарушен.

Comment: @Aleskandr, ну у меня такой же случай, я пользуюсь таким и у меня всё нормально определяет

Comment: @Aleskandr, можете кинуть фотку или загрузить сюда код head, скрипта 1 и скрипта 2?

Comment: @Aleskandr, насколько помню, вы спрашивали на счёт ajax )

Comment: добавил коды скриптов

Comment: @Aleskandr, не понял? За что правильно отметил, если не работает?

Comment: да, из другого не получается. Убрал отметку) Если в одном - то работает.

Comment: @Aleskandr, а если создать третий скрипт в котором укажем только эту функцию?

Comment: Yuri - не, смысл из этого скрипта запустить. Так можно каждую функцию выносить)

Comment: @Aleskandr, запишите так: `function compareInit() {return /* тут объект из new InSales.Compare()*/}` и потом вызывайте так: `new InSales.Compare(compareInit())`

Comment: @Aleskandr, я тут какой то костыль сочиняю )

Comment: можно пример, а то не соображу что делать)

Comment: @Aleskandr, смотрите

Comment: Yuri - так не работает вообще.

Comment: @Aleskandr, попробуй вместо `function compareInit() {...}` указать это: `$(document).ajaxSuccess(function(event, xhr, settings) {...}` и вызвать ajax

Answer (score 0):

Загружайте файлы в нужном порядке и будет Вас счастье.

В древние времена, порядок не гарантировал очерёдность, да и сейчас со всякими `async` и `defer` ситуация чуть путается.

Используйте [`defer`](https://learn.javascript.ru/external-script) для указания зависимости или систему зависимостей, коих много (правда в чистом виде их уже немного).

[Посмотреть (сниппет не поддерживает файлы)](https://plnkr.co/edit/wYVUaDxpQhHVV8DriFjh?p=preview).

Answer (score 0):

Как уже сказано, порядок загрузки скриптов будет гарантирован, если ввести атрибут [defer](https://learn.javascript.ru/external-script):

```
<script src="скрипт №1" defer></script>
<script src="скрипт №2" defer></script>
```